# Transparent image with shadow on android screen

Tags: android, image, transparent, shadow

I created a transparent image using gimp, and used it as Android apk icon. But when I installed the apk on my Galaxy S3, there is a shadow when display the icon on my screen. Since I can't post image as a new user, I posted the image at: 
http://www.guangnaqu.com/P1030055.JPG

Please noticed that other apks' icons are ok. Also the icon displayed ok on Android emulator.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your actual image?

Comment: the link you provided for image is not working

Answer (score 0):

It might be TouchWiz causing the problem.

I had a similar issue in a previous form of TouchWiz where it would make an entirely new color background of its choosing.

1.Edit it with GIMP http://www.gimp.org/ for an invisible background. *just throwing out options JIC it is the image editor*

2.Try to give the background something like a 0.05% Shader background setting that cannot be distinguished by the phone screen, but is seen by the UI.

Comment: Just a beginner with GIMP. Couldn't follow your steps. Please provide more details. For your reference, I uploaded my picture at: http://www.guangnaqu.com/temp/guangnaqu-global-130.png. Thanks a lot.